# startup message in Centos 7: could not boot

Tags: centos, boot, swap, initramfs, dracut

Dead community,

Does anyone know the solution to this error message that I get when starting **Centos Linux (3.10.0-1160.66.1.el7.x86_64) 7 (Core)**

```
[ 198.942749] dracut-initqueuel3371: Warning: /dev/centos/root does not exist
[ 198.9438971 dracut-initqueue[337]: Warning: /dev/centos/swap does not exist
[ 198.9433781 dracut-initqueue[337]: Warning: /dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-00a7896a:5363ef2f:ccd81c8f:8e11e69e does not exist
[ 198.9436701 dracut-initqueue[337]: Warning: /dev/mapper/centos-root does not exist

Starting Dracut Emergency Shell...

Warning: /dev/centos/root does not exist
Varning: /dev/centos/swp does not exist
Warning: /dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-md-uuid-00a7896a:5363ef2f:ccd81c8f:8e11e69e does not exist
Warning: /dev/mapper/centos-root does not exist

Generating “/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt"

Entering emergency mode. Exit the shell to continue.
Type ”journalctl” to view system logs.
You might want to save "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt” to a USB stick or /boot
after mounting them and attach it to a bug report.

dracut:/#
```

Comment: Was it working before? Did you make something unusual before this happened? In short: any context to add?

Comment: It was working normally, the server has logical raid configured

Comment: dracut:/# lsblk

- sh: lsblk: command not found
 dracut:/# df —h

- sh: df: command not found

 dracut:/# df -Th

- sh: df: command not found

1 dracut :/4 fsck

1 f£sck from util-1linux 273.7
> dracut:/4 _

Comment: It's telling it didn't find the Volume Group centos and its various Logical Volumes, and the MD (raid) component (which would have provided the PV I guess). the relevant file that has to be exported elsewhere somehow because the environment is too limited is the file stored in RAM: /run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt which might have more information. I wouldn't know how to proceed because that's debugging and it's interactive.

Comment: Dear @A.B at this point I have given up on recovering the boot system, but something can be done for data recovery, you have a tool to recover my data from the disks

Comment: Dear @Stéphane Chazelas